# Modifying a pandas dataframe that may be a view

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas `DataFrame` `df` that is returned from a function and I generally don't know whether it is an independent object or a view on another `DataFrame`. I want to add new columns to it but don't want to copy it unnecessarily.

```
df['new_column'] = 0
```

may give a nasty warning about modifying a copy

```
df = df.copy()
```

may be expensive if df is large.
What's the best way here?

Comment: df['new_column'] = 0 should not raise the warning imo, maybe you did a copy of that df before that?

Comment: s = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2], 'b':[2,3]})
s1=s[s.a>1]

s1['c'] = 0
s1['c'] = 0
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\__main__.py:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  if __name__ == '__main__':

Comment: `s1=s[s.a>1]` is where you create the problem

Answer (score 0):

you should use an indexer to create your s1 such has:

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2], 'b':[2,3]})
indexer = s[s.a > 1].index
s1 = s.loc[indexer, :]
s1['c'] = 0
```

should remove the warning.

Comment: Indexing with a list always creates a copy but that's not what my question is about. I am _given_ a DataFrame that may or may not be a view. I want to add a new column to it (if the frame is a view then, obviously, I need to make a copy; but if it's not a view then I don't want to copy it.

Comment: [read this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy)